# Dynamically alter URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, url

Please how can I change the feed URL in this script with link(href)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#test').rssfeed('http://feeds.reuters.com/reuters/oddlyEnoughNews');
});
</script>
<div id="test"> </div>
```

See example here http://www.zazar.net/developers/jquery/zrssfeed/example.html

The test Div displays the content of the `rss feed`

I just want to be able to alter the `rssfeed(url)` by clicking links with diffrent rssfeed url

```
<a onclick ="rssfeed('http://feeds.cnn.com/News');"></a>
```

Comment: What does `dynamically` mean in your case? What is `rssfeed`? Where is the HTML for `#test`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

note sure how you'd want the link to load it, but I'm assuming on click so this is what I would do..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.rss').click(function(){
    $('#test').rssfeed($(this).attr('href'));
  })
});
</script>

<a class="rss" href="http://feeds.reuters.com/reuters/oddlyEnoughNews">load rss</a>
<div id="test"> </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As it is shown here: http://www.zazar.net/developers/jquery/zrssfeed/example_menu.html

One can simply change the feed by calling `.rssfeed` again.

Comment: I was going to write the same solution as Yohn did but he posted it first and it is already perfect so I let my answer how it is. :)